# Android App Stuck on White Blank Screen, looks like it's Facebook Android SDK 4.36.0 Issue

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, version

Everything was perfectly working few days ago(till 31st August 2018 morning), suddenly the app got stuck with white blank screen. I did some debug and search on it. And found that my app is not even opening splash screen and all I get in logcat is: 
**com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers: getAttributionIdentifiers should not be called from the main thread**

I also updated the Facebook SDK with latest one **[Facebook Android SDK 4.36.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x)** which seems updated on 29th August 2018.

If I removed the Facebook SDK, it works properly but not with it.

Need some help!

Answer (score 5):

"compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'" does not give me a white screen "compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.0' does give me a white screen.
"compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)');" also gives me a white screen, this is what I have been using for about 4 months.

So, 4.35.0 fixes that problem, as does removing all the Facebook code.

Comment: Right answer! There is an issue with 4.36.0 version

Comment: Thanks @user2680414. 
I tried with different versions of Facebook SDK for Android. It seems latest version and dynamic version has this issue.

**Tested and with Issues SDKs:**
1. `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.0'  `
2. `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' `

**Tested & Working SDKs:**
1. `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'`
2. `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0' `
3. `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'`

Answer (score -1):

Change to version 4.35.0

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'
```