# E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory only on Android Q (API 29)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex

I have searched everywhere about this and still have no solution.

The gradle has minSdkVersion 21 and targetSdkVersion 29

I got error only in API 29, then the app doesn't load and show up blank screen. When i see logcat it gives an error like this :

```
E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packagename.appname-BxS7Zs-h0IWwJAVhbjx7aQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.packagename.appname-BxS7Zs-h0IWwJAVhbjx7aQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:256)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:370)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1941)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:541)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:349)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:908)
```

I think it seems like from multidex, then i have tried adding following code to gradle app

> multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
>
> multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')

my multidex-config.txt

```
com/packagename/appname/androidx.class
```

my multidex-config.pro

```
-keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }
```

my App class extending MultiDexApplication

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

my Manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/main"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

my gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

my gradle/app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packagename.appname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.yanzhenjie.zbar:camera:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.5.0'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.0'

    implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0'
}
```

I really need a solution for this. Help me please, thank you so much!

Comment: See a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438312/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-my-app-name-androidx or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700486/didnt-find-class-androidx-core-app-corecomponentfactory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is pointing to the use of `androidx` `CoreComponentFactory` class(using AndroidX) but you are using old package `com.android.support:multidex`

so use `androidx` dependency as:

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
```

and make sure to use `androidx` imports in the application class as

```
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;
import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

public class YourApp extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        MultiDex.install(this);
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }
}
```

Additionally: During the app Load-up, android Q uses the `CoreComponentFactory` instance internally whether you are using it in manifest or not, which is causing the issue.

Also, add `multiDexEnabled true` as `defaultConfig{multiDexEnabled true }`

---

**Update:** After the RCA, the `componentfactory` import issue was resolved with the `androidx` lib imports though there was another issue with the facebook sdk dependency in version `4.36.0` which was resolved by downgrading the version to `4.35.0`(or use latest version integration) and also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161288/android-app-stuck-on-white-blank-screen-looks-like-its-facebook-android-sdk-4/52316551).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointing out that i wrongly using the old package. I have change it now to use androidx, but unfortunately the error still appear. Is my file in multiDexKeepFile correct?

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA try adding `androidx/core/app/CoreComponentFactory.class` and probably this in proguard `-keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { <init>(); }` though first make sure to clear or rebuild, probably invalidatecahche and restart. I hope now you are using `androidx` imports in application class as well

Comment: I added both codes, in application class already using androidx imports. I did clean and rebuild then invalidate cache n restart. After the android studio launched i did clean and rebuild again. The error still appear :(

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA try adding `multiDexEnabled true` inside `defaultConfig{multiDexEnabled true }`

Comment: well, then I guess nothing much is left, I guess you tried the rebuild again though would be great if you can share a repo with minimal problematic code

Comment: i can share u the repo, we can continue in chat

Comment: sounds like a plan

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA I mean share the link and I will look at it

Comment: Can i send u in private? like collaborator in github maybe

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA sure

Comment: And your email?

Comment: `pavneet.edu@gmail.com` though it available in my bio too :)

Comment: oh sorry. i added you

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this error occurred. But I faced a similar situation, and the solution in my case was to delete two lines in the manifest.

```
<application
...
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="androidx"
>
```

I don't know if it's the smartest solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to add Java 1.8 compatibility

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

add that code into your `android { }` at app/build.gradle

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I already have that in my gradle app, the app still doesn't load, show up blank screen and gives the error

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Pavneet_Singh answer:

i had both lines

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

i removed additional line:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

and this error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think that you have a double call to `MultiDex.install(this)` because subclassing the `MultiDexApplication` class calls this for you and then you are also explicitly calling it. So this may have been part of the issue I guess.

However, I had a similar problem and none of the above answers fixed it.

Our app has been around for some time (before API 21 / Android 5), and had an explicit implementation of Multidex.

```kotlin
class MyApplication : SomeOtherApplication() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }
}
```

Removing the mutliDex implementation and gradle dependency,

```
dependencies {
  implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

then rebuilding the app immeditately resolved the problem.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-on-l) states that as of minSdkVersion 21 multiDex is enabled by default and therefore the subclassing of the `MultiDexApplication` class like in the question or our implementation is no longer required.

So it would also appear like you could remove your multiDex related implementation and perhaps overcome the problem too.

For the record, although it doesn't appear to be relevant here, it is also possible to remove some of the other gradle configurations relating to multiDex as they are enabled by default. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39932549/2199001)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the "buildToolsVersion" in "build.gradle" and then doing a "Rebuild" solved my issue

android {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have already updated the gradle with the latest version like u said but still no luck

Comment: I had done everything except this, which solve my problem exactly ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to not configure multidex manually

Application class

```
//Remove unused imports
public class App extends Application { //change MultiDexApplication 
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        //MultiDex.install(this); //comment this
    }
}
```

gradle:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packagename.appname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt') //comment this
            //multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro') //comment this
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt') //comment this
            //multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro') //comment this
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1' //comment this

    implementation 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.yanzhenjie.zbar:camera:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.5.0'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.0'

    implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have tried to commenting multidex dependencies, multiDexKeepFile and Proguard, then changing my App class extending Application and still no luck the app still doesn't load and blank..

Comment: is there any difference with the log?

Comment: Its still the same

Comment: have you clean project and/or invalidate caches/restart and/or rebuild project?

Comment: it is possible that your app execute MultiDex.install() or any other code through reflection or JNI before MultiDex.install() is complete. so it can caused ClassNotFoundException.

if with changes that i suggested still not work even not make the logs any difference, you should check all your dependecies. good luck

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused due to using both androidx and legacy android support libraries

Just open `project structure` and go to `Dependencies` and select `All Modules` and check is there any library which contains `android.support`

Just replace that with `androidx` version for that `library`

In the latest versions of android studio, just REMOVE these lines if it is there inside the manifest file

```
<application
...
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"  // REMOVE THIS
android:appComponentFactory="androidx"       // REMOVE THIS
>
```

If still it doesn't helps try this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74523286/6236959

Answer (score -1):

The situation I encountered is that my application uses a system signature, and this problem is also encountered in Android Q. No matter how I change it, I can’t change it. Just change the signature later.