# My App is not starting , with following error

Tags: android, android-studio

my app is not starting, my logcat is below, I don't able to understand this error, I m beginer,
what mistakes I have done so I m   getting this error, I found similar a Qestion here but the answers is too confusing I don't able to get [E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory only on Android Q (API 29)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60472222/e-loadedapk-unable-to-instantiate-appcomponentfactory-only-on-android-q-api-29/64175787#64175787)

also getting this

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.

```
E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: 
DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.whatsapp-fssQPC-1LXhux2cD4hnAgQ==/lib/arm64, 
/data/app/com.whatsapp-fssQPC-1LXhux2cD4hnAgQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:228)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:340)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5451)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1756)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:475)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:310)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:853)
```

My gradle.build is

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.somusmall"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true


    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


implementation 'com.agrawalsuneet.androidlibs:dotsloader:1.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

}

My Menifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".video_layout" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Splash_Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the above class to proguard-rules.

```
 -keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }
```

https://dzone.com/articles/enabling-proguard-for-android

Works for me. :)

Comment: keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }  i didn't get it can you please explain little more, i,e steps what exactly i have to do

Comment: how can i do that?